# OneNote COM Interface - Ink Support

Tags: com, onenote, onenote-api

Is it possible to get access to the user's ink/highlighting through the COM extension interface for MS OneNote?

Answer (score 0):

Highlights do appear - try it out and take a look at the XML - there are some styles applied inline. Inks do come in, either as InkDrawing, InkWord, or InkParagraph.  InkDrawing's are pure strokes, whereas the others are handwriting-recognized ink.

EDIT:
I just updated the Vanilla COM Add-in to make it easy for you to see XML, so you can analyze after experimenting on pages.  You can find it here: https://github.com/OneNoteDev/VanillaAddIn

Comment: I'm having a really hard time getting started with the Vanilla COM Add-in project. The directions are not clear enough for a Visual Studio/COM Add-in newbie. Are there any more detailed tutorials availible? I keep on getting blocked from developing for the platform because of this entry barrier.